# Unable to debug React Native in Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to work on react native for android application development. I am using android studio for that, but I am unable to debug the .js files developed for react native. Whenever there is any problem with code its giving me error, Unexpected Token, I am unable to know that how to debug or get proper error. Is there any framework available to work on React native for Android app development. I have already figured out a lot but unable to get any solution to debug android app based on React Native.

Answer (score 3):

You can debug JavaScript code, console.log etc in Chrome. You have to select "Debug in Chrome" from the developer menu on device first and that will open a new tab on Chrome at localhost:8081/debugger-ui. However, to debug in Chrome, keep in mind you have to install React Developer Tools on Chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi

Answer (score 1):

You need to debug in Chrome. There are good docs on the RN site about debugging: 
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#content

However, if you have syntax errors the debugger won't help you, but Chrome Dev tools might give you a better idea of where the error is.

Comment: But it will work for code written for web, means by using ReactDom but my problem is to debug code written for android mobile app. Please guide me.

Comment: It will work for JS code written for android mobile app too. You can put debug points in Chrome Developer Tools in your JS files for mobile app same as for ReactDom. Debugging in Chrome is (let's say) pretty much the same, you can console.log from your JS files for mobile apps, and you will see it in console on chrome. Take a look at my example: http://i.stack.imgur.com/sA6Eu.png